# Get an array of strings after $lookup instead of an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I'm trying to join my members collection with a email collection, which works. But it is showing an array of email objects and I only need an array email addresses. The email address is a field of the email collection. A member can have multiple email addresses. The result should show all the fields from the member collection plus the additional address field.

### Members collection

```
_id: 62692f3503ed123e35a56a12
name: "John",
lastName: "Cena",
// arbitrary number of fields
```

### Emails Collection

```
_id: 74331a2663ed999e35a33a09
memberId: 62692f3503ed123e35a56a12,
email: "john@john.com"
```

### I tried

```
db.members.aggregate([{"$lookup" : {from: "emails",localField: "_id",foreignField: "memberId",as: "emails"},
```

**Result**

```
_id: 62692f3503ed123e35a56a12
name: "John",
lastName: "Cena",
emails: [
{
  _id:
  memberId: 62692f3503ed123e35a56a12,
  email: "john@john.com"
},
{...}
]
```

### What I need

```
_id: 62692f3503ed123e35a56a12
name: "John",
lastName: "Cena",
emails: ["john@john.com", "..."]
// any other fields
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$map](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) as part of [$addFields](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage to convert `$lookup` result:

```
db.members.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup" : {
            from: "emails",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "memberId",
            as: "emails"}
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            emails: { $map: { input: "$emails", as: "$$this.email" } }
        }
    }
]);
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NF7bzi3f2zM)

Comment: What if the members collection has an arbitrary number of fields that I want to receive in the result, without having to specify them all manually? (updated the question, should have been more specific)

Comment: @Calypso I've updated my answer, `$addFields` will only overwrite `emails` and keep other fields